# How to write workflow rule to work in both criteria are met and Formula evaluates to true

Tags: workflow

In workflow rule criteria are Met can be done in formula evaluates to true

[image]

The samething I am doing in formula evaluates to true:

[image]

Formula evaluates to true is working but criteria are met is not working,Please anyone guide me for the answer,what i am doing wrong in criteria met

Comment: In `Value` column, you have to put the word `null`

Comment: @ihassan i have tried null, if you are not giving null also, it takes null value only

Comment: @ihssan - That is not correct. Null is expressed as no value in the value field. Actually putting null in the value represents the word null

Comment: @user36188 - how are you evaluating if the WFR is evaluating? Is it on record creation or edit? If editing, did the record meet the WFR criteria before the edit was made? To validate, change criteria to "created and every time it is edited" and try again. If it works then you need to read up and understand how your current selection works

Comment: @Eric I have selected the option created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria for this only not working

Comment: @user36188 - yup, hence my comment. Read it, digest it, do it, report back. You may just be misunderstanding the option you selected.

Comment: @user36188 - HOW ARE YOU TESTING THE EDIT PART. DEOS IT MEET THE CRITERIA BEFORE YOU EDIT. If so then it is working as expected and you need to UNDERSTAND the option you selected

Comment: what is the field type of the JDE_Ship... field?

Comment: ok Thankyou it is working @Guy and Eric, sorry one minor mistake i have done,Now it is working

Comment: @user36188 curious what did u find the issue to be. Glad u got it sorted though

Comment: @Eric `Account: Record Type` in criteria is referencing Id of Record Type

Comment: @Oleksiy - Record Type is the TEXT value not the ID in a Workflow rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a different value for the Record Type in each example.  It appears you are using the *DeveloperName* when using criteria met.  Try changing the value to "Business Account - FR" and see if it works.